# ng-click stops working after first click, but only in later angular versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

So I have made this very simple script to isolate the problem. I tested with different versions of angular and in the fiddle if you select version 1.1.1 it works fine. You can hit the add button as many times as you want. Newer versions seem to have a problem with this approach. Is this a bug, a security measure or should I just write a directive? In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pygksyq0/) I am loading the latest version, but you can remove this version and change this to 1.1.1 and it will work. Also, 1.2.1 has the same problem. Thanks in advance for any tips.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in naam">
            <div>{{item}}</div>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.naam = [
            "1",
            "2"];
        $scope.add = function () {
            var x = 3;
            var y = 4;
            $scope.naam.push(x, y);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a bug of Angular. Actually, you got an error, `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]` because it's trying to add the same key into the array and the `ng-repeat` doesn't allow it.

So, you have to use `track by` as following:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in naam track by $index">
        <div>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
```

Here is an upadated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pygksyq0/1/).

Comment: Ok thanks! I was so confused of why this happened since older version did allow this. So let me understand: the index is used to repeat the values instead of the values itself. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. FYI, the reason that your code does work on an older version, 1.1.1, and doesn't on the newer version because since AngularJS 1.2.x, it doesn't allow duplicate keys in repeaters anymore.

Comment: @LVarayut Interesting. What is the behavior of the $id() function mentioned in NgRepeat API (v. higher than 1.2.x)? For example: `item in items` is equivalent to `item in items track by $id(item)`. ?https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @klode Honestly, I have never used `$id()` but I think so. Basically, Angular automatically adds `$$hashkey` to each element in the `ng-repeat` in order to track them using the added `$$hashkey`. So, if you write `track by $id(item)`, this also tells Angular to track by `$$hashkey` again. Logically, it is equivalent. You can take a look at this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBwE0mNehx8) for more understanding and look at this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pygksyq0/5/).

Comment: Thanks @LVarayut ! So if `ng-repeat=item in [1, 4, 4]` the last two elements `4`  will be assigned  the same identical $$hashKey therefore resulting in duplicate error?

Comment: Actually, the document is written that `item in items is equivalent to item in items track by $id(item). This implies that the DOM elements will be associated by item identity in the array.` In conclusion, Angular keeps data as dictionary, key and value as item and DOM. When the `track by` isn't specified, the item will be used as a key and `$$hashkey` will be inserted to track DOM change. So, you can't have duplicate items. On the other hand, if the `track by key` was used, Angular will use this key instead and also use this key to track the DOM, so `$$hashkey` isn't needed anymore.

Comment: @LVarayut thanks! That is the exact sentence in the docs that I have trouble understanding. From the docs, I personally find it really hard to understand how ng-repeat is implemented.